# Is there any difference in setting path for golang, python or java in ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, bashrc, paths, etc

In some tutorials path is set in ~/.profile however in some other tutorials they use etc/path or ~/.bashrc, can you explain whats the difference and how it works in linux ubuntu. I am sorry for such a basic question but I am using linux for the first time in my life. Or if someone could guide to a tutorial which explains the whole path setting concept.